# Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I am getting this error while I am using the jquery.validate.js. The error appears when the page loads. I have tried to use various divs but not successfully. Please help me out.

I've seen many questions answered that it may be due to the div but I am not getting what to do as I have tried to put the form tags outside every div but the issue remains the same.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form id="update_form">
  <div class="subscribebox">
    <div class="updateheading">Want Updates?</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" required placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#update_form").validate();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You have to call $("#update_form").validate(); onclick event or any other event. Currently is fire when page load.

Comment: You're using the jQuery form validator, not jQuery validate. Therefore there is no `validate()` method. You need to use `$.validate()` along with `data` attributes on the form inputs as in their example: http://www.formvalidator.net/#reg-form

Comment: @VishalKamal no this is not the solution!

Comment: @VishalKamal even if the OP was using the jQuery validate library, that's completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$(function() {
  $.validate({
    form: '#update_form'
  })
});
```

rather than

```
$(function() {
    $("#update_form").validate();
  });
```

Shows that it resolves the error on the load.

```js
$(function() {
  $.validate({
    form: '#update_form'
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form id="update_form">
  <div class="subscribebox">
    <div class="updateheading">Want Updates?</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" required placeholder="Enter your email address" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submitbtn">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Try applying this solution, maybe it resolves your bug.

*If still you have any issue, feel free to comment.*